# How to cut a txt to a matrix in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I've got a txt which looks like this:

```
JB651 ACDCCADBCADCDA
JB831 ACACCBBBBBDDAC
JC124 DACBDBBACBDCDC
JD329 BAACDBABCCDDAB
JD830 BDDCDBABBBAAAD
JI428 DCBCCBBBBCCCCA
```

And I have to cut it to a matrix (I would say first I have to count the lines for a `for` loop) looks like this:

```
[[JI428] [D,C,B,C,C,B,B,B,B,C,C,C,C,A]]
```

And then, how can I refer to any line or letter of the 2nd part? (I'm a totally beginer)

Comment: Is this text stored in a text file OR csv file or something?
Is is simply stored as a string?

Comment: Give it a try and see where that goes. Come back with what you tried and a specific question.  No one really wants to write this for you. Hint: the _first_ thing you need to do is break down your problem into algorithms and processes. Forget looping for now. How would you, given a string containing a single line, transform it into your output format?  If necessary, break that problem down into understandable pieces. Coding is often starting in the middle and working out.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file and read each line, splitting at the space present. To be able to access any line and thus any letter, it may be best to use a dictionary:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
  f = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in f]

final_data = {a:list(b) for a, b in f}
```

Output:

```
{'JD830': ['B', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'D'], 'JC124': ['D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'C'], 'JB651': ['A', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'A'], 'JB831': ['A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C'], 'JD329': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'B'], 'JI428': ['D', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A']}
```

You can access the rows by passing a key from the first column:

```
print(final_data['JD830'])
```

Output:

```
['B', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'D']
```